# Refresh Recyclerview from another Activity

Tags: android, sqlite, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have my main Activity with a fragment, which has a Recyclerview retrieving all the data populated from the database. In this fragment I got a button which calls another activity to insert an object into the database.

The problem is when the Activity ends and returns to the Main Activity the Recyclerview doesn't show the new item I just created. I tried with this piece of code:

```
 @Override
    public void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            adapterItem.addItem(MyApplication.getWritableDatabase().getAllItems());
            listProjectsView.scrollToPosition(0);
        }
```

The function getAllItems retrieve all the data from sqlite.

On my adapterItem from my Recyclerview I got this:

```
public void addItem(ArrayList<Item> listItems) {
        this.listItems = listItems;
        notifyItemInserted(0);
    }
```

It works "fine". The main problem is when I switch to another application in progress in my mobile and I return to my developed app the *onResume* method switches on and show again my last insert, populating twice this item (and so on if I do it again).

Thanks

Comment: use onRestart insted of onResume

Comment: use must take `HashSet` which will exclude the duplicate element

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Pass the new item back to MainActivity, then deal with it yourself.

1.In MainActivity, use `startActivityForResult` to start the second Activity, like this:

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class), REQUEST_CODE);
```

`REQUEST_CODE` is an `int`.

2.In second Activity, override `finish` like this:

```
@Override
public void finish() {
    Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
    returnIntent.putExtra("passed_item", itemYouJustCreated);
    // setResult(RESULT_OK);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent); //By not passing the intent in the result, the calling activity will get null data.
    super.finish();
}
```

3.In MainActivity, override `onActivityResult` like this:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        YourItem passedItem = data.getExtras().get("passed_item");
        // deal with the item yourself

    }
}
```

Comment: recyclerview click event is in RecyclerView's adapter, not in MainActivity,so how can i get for that?

Comment: Thanks for accepting my edit Wesley and thank you for your answer, you greatly helped on the project I'm working on :)

Answer (score 3):

You can create static recyclerview (let say mRecyclerview) in the activity(let say firstActivity) which displays your recyclerview .
And when you add new item to your list in the other activity(let say secondActivity), you can just use

```
     firstActivity.mRecyclerview.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
```

I use this way for a while and didn't encounter any performance drawback but test it with your own code for sure.

Comment: its a valid method, but it will only work when the Adapter is updated in the second activity like this : firstActivity.mRecyclerview.setAdapter(List<data>);

Answer (score 1):

If it may help someone...

I had the same:
"I have my MainActivity with a fragment, which has a `RecyclerView` retrieving all the data populated from the database. In this fragment, I got a button that calls another `activity(insertA)` to insert an object into the database.

The problem was when the `activity(insertA)` ends and returns to the Main Activity the `RecyclerView` doesn't show the new item I just created."

So I used this in `Fragment` button which calls another `activity(insertA)` I just called

```
btn_addNew.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, insertA.class);
        startActivity(myIntent);
    }
});
```

WITHOUT FINISHING with `finish();` !!!!!!!!!!!!

In `insertA` Activity in the method `AddNewThingToTheDataBase()` insted of `finish();` or `startActivity(Intent);` just put `onBackPressed();`

```
public void AddNewThingToTheDataBase(){
    *****Inserting in DB code;
    onBackPressed();
}
```

And in Fragment(or where your RecyclerView is located) add this code

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    *YourUpdateRecyleViewFunction();*
}
```

**UPD:**
Read your question one more time and decided to add some info to my answer.
Because of this ".addItem" method your app onResume thinks that you are still adding new item. You need to add some sort of checking before notifying the adapter with ".addItem".

It should be something like this:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if(itemWasAdded){ adapterItem.addItem(MyApplication.getWritableDatabase().getAllItems());
           listProjectsView.scrollToPosition(0);
           itemWasAdded=false;
        }
    }
```

In that case your app onResume will understand that the item Was Added and will notify the adapter and if the item was already added or not added, then the adapter will not be notified.
And don't forget to create a logic for the boolean "itemWasAdded"! So it would be true only if the item was inserted!

Answer (score 0):

Try Like this,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Context, YourClass);
startActivityForResult(intent, ADD_ITEM);

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == ADD_ITEM){
            adapterItem.addItem(MyApplication.getWritableDatabase().getAllItems());
            listProjectsView.scrollToPosition(0);
        }
    }       
}
```

hope it will work for you

Comment: I tried this once but i was not able to get the add animation to show for the recyclerview - i guess it adds it before the activity became fully visible. Do you know how I can add an item from another activity and have the addition be animated on the recyclerview when I navigate back to my mainactivity?

Answer (score 0):

You can make the `recyclerView` static and initialize it in `onCreate` method

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    protected static RecyclerView recyclerView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.notes_recycler_view);
        
        displayDataOnRecyclerView(this);

    }
```

Then create a method in MainActivity to display the data in the `recyclerView`

```
public static void displayDataOnRecyclerView(Context context) {

    //using a Linear Layout Manager
RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

//data that will be displayed in the adapter from sqlite database
DatabaseHandler databaseHandler = new DatabaseHandler(context);
List<Model> data = databaseHandler.getAllData();

//specifying the adapter
RecyclerView.Adapter adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(data,context);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Finally, call the `displayDataOnRecyclerView` method in the other Activity

```
MainActivity.displayDataOnRecyclerView(otherActivity.this);
```